# UICollectionView images loading issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

`UICollectionView` is used to display images. It works fine.

Issue is when I scroll `UICollectionView`, some of the cells which were visible are now non-visible and when I scroll back so that they are visible again, I see that they are not properly displayed.

So what happens is that `imageA` is at index 0 and `imageB` is at index 1. Now after scrolling and coming back original scroll position when those cells are loaded again, their position is either switched or both the cell have same images.

**Initially :**

[image]

**After reloading cells :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

    DLog(@"url at index %d : %@", indexPath.row, ((MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).imageUrl);

    MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Get image in separate thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Get image to display
        UIImage * tempImage = object.image;

        if (tempImage)
        {
            // Run code to set image to UIImageView in main thread only.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                cell.imageView.image = tempImage;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // Download failed.
            DLog(@"Downloaded image is nil.");
        }
    });

    return cell;
}
```

I log the value of image url and it is logging correct value.

Comment: one suggestion, can you try downloading required images first and reload the collection view.

Comment: @user2071152 I do that.

Comment: Why do you need this asynchronous blocks at all? At least why two inside each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also used that trick, but the threads and the indexes between threads make a mess so I searched and I found a great library on GitHub.

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];

    DLog(@"url at index %d : %@", indexPath.row, ((MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).imageUrl);

    MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: hi EridB , have a side question (different topic coming from looking at your gist of code above) concerning that "DLog" . Is that a third party library? or custom logging that you created for your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are wondering that after some time they switch to their positions? You call

```
cell.imageView.image = tempImage;
```

asynchronously. That means that execution doesn't wait while image changes and displays dequeued cell with old image.

Comment: Why they switch to their positions is because you call cell.imageView.image = tempImage; and you say imageUrls are right. Why they appear in wrong and unpredictable positions when you scroll  up is because you dequeue reusable cell and you cannot predict which one you will get here. This is how this mechanism works: if you can see, say, 10 cell at the same time there is no reason to create more then 10 cells. When you need display 11th, you take some of invisible at the moment cells and change it's content.

Comment: How to then disable reusing of cell? I tried setting dummy id to cell but then it throws error. Also tried using `nil` for id.

Comment: Answering on your question literally, you can use [[MyCell alloc] init] methods for each cell instead of dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, but is very very bad. Just imagine if user scrolls fast back and forth how many resources will be allocated, deallocated and allocated and deallocated... Try instead not to use async blocks. If your images are cached in memory , is it really that slow to assign another image that you need to do it asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here, but mainly the problem you are seeing is because the cell reference is no longer pointing to the same Cell. As a learning exercise, keeping your code (or at least the general layout of your code), you can overcome the issue by getting a reference to the cell you intended the item to be applied to via the indexPath and if it's still being displayed, assign the image.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];

    DLog(@"url at index %d : %@", indexPath.item, ((MyObject *)[self.list.array  objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]).imageUrl);

    MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    // get a weak reference to collectionViewController (assume your code is in a UICollectionViewCcontroller)

    __weak MyCollectionViewController *weakSelf = self; 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

     // Get image to display
      UIImage * tempImage = object.image;

     // check if the cell is still visible
     if ([weakSelf.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {

          if (tempImage)
          {
            // Run code to set image to UIImageView in main thread only.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               // we get a reference to the cell via it's indexPath
                MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[weakSelf.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.imageView.image = tempImage;
            });
         }
         else
        {
          // Download failed.
          DLog(@"Downloaded image is nil.");
        }
     }
    });

  return cell;
}
```

It would certainly be better, as Erid suggested, that you use something like SDWebImage and store the image url in your MyObject Class and set the cell.imageView.image using SDWebimage's setImageWithURL (personally i would write the image retrieval and image reference in the object class).

Oh, one minor point, you should use indexPath.section and indexPath.item for UICollectionViews and indexPath.row for UITableView.s

Comment: Great solution. In my case, I also added a placeholder right under dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: and then the code you posted above takes care of the rest, showing the images only when the download is finished. Thanks a lot.